# Serialization of 'Illuminate\\Http\\UploadedFile' is not allowed when using image intervention cache

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to cache images using image intervention , but i'm getting this error

> "Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed".

Here is my function in controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $fileName = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $width= $request->width;
        $height = $request->height;

        $img = ImageInt::cache(function($image_resize) use($request,$width,$height,$fileName){

           return  $image_resize->make($request->image)->resize($width,$height)->save('storage/'.$fileName);
            // $image_resize->save('storage/'.$fileName);
        },10,true);
   ...}
}
```

Comment: please next time do some research before posting a question. check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552818/laravel-queue-error-serialization-of-illuminate-http-uploadedfile-is-not-allow

Comment: thank you for trying to help me, but this question is not that much related to that one.

Comment: it seems the exact problem you have. You can not serialize a file uploaded. You have to save on the disk.